# "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent." When returning HttpResponseMessage with HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm using the new Web Api beta and wish to return

`HttpResponseMessage<MyObject>(new MyObject{ MyMessage = "Go Away!" }, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)`

from one of my ApiController actions.

Forms Authentication hijacks the response, crashes and adds the error `"Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent."` and it's html to the response.

Normal suppression techniques like [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx) don't work with Web Api.

Has anyone found a work around to this?

I've looked at [this forum post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1772764.aspx/1) where people report the same problem but the solutions there don't work for this case. The first solution suggested uses the normal suppression technique which doesn't work for web api. The second uses a HttpMessageHandler to intercept the request before it gets to the controller, I want the controller to fire as normal.

After looking into the `DelegatingHandler` I can get access to the `HttpResponseMessage` but have no idea what to do with it to stop FormsAuth from redirecting.

Comment: Explaining why the proposed solutions don't work might be helpful here.

Comment: So why do _normal  suppression techniques_ like the ones mentioned in Phil Haack blog post work? They are meant for REST services like the WebAPI.

Comment: @Maurice I have no idea, the web api returns the correct 401 but adds the error html to the response. Phil Haacks code has no effect for web api actions. It fires but doesn't help. Stepping through it, it also crashes on `response.StatusCode = 401;` with "Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.". The response.StatusCode is already 401 at this point so I think the error happens somewhere else in the pipeline.

Comment: Phil's post points out it's the FormsAuthenticationModule that changes the 401 to a 302. You are claiming that removing the FormsAuthenticationModule has no effect for you. Now I am not arguing you don't need the FormsAuthenticationModule as you might. But then again there is nothing in your post about using it either. However your error sounds like you are doing something that is causing the FormsAuthenticationModule to fail when changing the 401 to a 302.

Comment: And just in case you where wondering. Using a plain vanilla ASP.NET Web API and adding the [Authorize] attribute results in the expected, but unwanted, 302 redirect being send to the client. So that part works out of the box. And the SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule works for me if I remove the test for XMLHttpRequest as I am using a console app as client.

Comment: Yes this works as expected when using the [Authorize] attribute, but not when returning HttpResponseMessage<MyObject>(new MyObject{ MyMessage = "Go Away!" }, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) from an action.  This seems to confuse it. Try creating an action that only returns this and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I found that just removing the Forms Auth section from the web.config worked for me, although that is only of any use if you're not also hosting web pages inside the same project that you're api is in.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue when using the [Phil Haack's SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx)

I managed to fix it in my case by clearing the server's error as shown below

```
private void OnEndRequest(object source, EventArgs args)
{
    var context = (HttpApplication)source;
    var response = context.Response;

    if (context.Context.Items.Contains(SuppressAuthenticationKey))
    {
        context.Server.ClearError(); //Clearing server error

        response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.StatusCode = 401;
        response.RedirectLocation = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me with ASP.NET Web API.  I only needed to use `context.Server.ClearError();` I conditionally call it from my Global.asax.cs `Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute` method.  This stopped ASP.NET from appending the redirect HTML after my JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

Hi as this question still seems to be open I thought I would point out that the latest MVC 4 RC release now appears to have the Forms redirect disabled by default. I did some digging whilst replying to this question [Prevent FormsAuthenticationModule of intercepting ASP.NET Web API responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087677/prevent-formsauthenticationmodule-of-intercepting-asp-net-web-api-responses/11099523#11099523)